# How do I include the sidebar (with Widgets) in a custom theme?

Tags: customization, widgets, sidebar

I have created a custom WordPress theme and need to be able to include the sidebar with widgets. I have the sidebar.php file, functions code and three widgets waiting to see the light of day. But alas, no dice.

Here is the sidebar.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The sidebar containing the main widget area
 *
 * If no active widgets are in the sidebar, hide it completely.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>

    <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
        </div><!-- #secondary -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the function call:

```
// Declare sidebar widget zone
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
      register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar Widgets',
        'id'   => 'sidebar-widgets',
        'description'   => 'These are widgets for the sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));
}

if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'main_nav' => 'Main Navigation Menu'
            )
        );
}
```

I am calling the sidebar as follows:

```
 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

I would appreciate any assistance in getting this to show correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the dynamic sidebar being called is not matching the ID of what is registered.

Matching:

```
 <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-widgets' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-widgets' ); ?>
        </div><!-- #secondary -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Register Sidebar

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
      register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Sidebar Widgets',
        'id'   => 'sidebar-widgets',
        'description'   => 'These are widgets for the sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));
}
```

`<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` tells your template to use the `sidebar.php` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have one big problem and then I would suggest a few suggestions on your code

- `sidebar-widgets != sidebar-1` You register a sidebar with id `sidebar-widgets` but you are calling `sidebar-1`
- You don't need to do this `if (function_exists('register_sidebar'))`. `register_sidebar` is a core function, so it will always exist. It is **not** wrong, but it wastes space :-) (my opinion)
- Wrap your `register_sidebar` function in a function and hook it to `widgets_init`. It just makes it so much easier to deregister a sidebar later on